# capture image from webcam and store

Tags: codeigniter

I want to capture image from webcam and store it to database and file path.but it will not stored in database also in file path.

My view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/dist/js/webcam.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-offset-3 no-print">
                                            <!--<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/blank.png" >-->
                                            <div class="clearfix" id="my_camera"></div><br>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="take_snapshot()"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i>Capture</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 imager" id="results">
                                            <!--<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/user.png" class="thumbnail" >-->
                                            <h3>Visitors Photo</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
<script language="JavaScript">
        function take_snapshot() {                
            Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {                    
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                        '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                        '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
            });
        }
    </script>
<script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md you can

```
 Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {                    
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                        '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                        '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
            });
```

must be like

```
Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {                    
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                            '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                            '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
                    Webcam.upload( data_uri, '<?php echo site_url('controlerfunctiontoupload'); ?>', function(code, text) {
            if (code == '200') {
              alert ('ok');
            } else {
              alert('error');
            }
        } );
                });
```

see in documentation

```
upload_name     "webcam"
```

in controler / function to upload

```
$filename='test.jpg';
$filepath=FCPATH.'folderWithRights0777/'.$filename;
    $result=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], $filepath));
```

also for insert in database

```
$this->db->from('files');
$this->db->set('image', $filename);
$this->db->insert();
```

Comment: i use follow your referal link above and use it in simple php it working but when i use it on codeigniter it shows an error that localhost says:Webcam.js Error: Could not locate DOM element to attach to. you can check now my code above only on view page not all i update in view page above.

Comment: You should initiate webcam after page load!
on document.ready event or to run javascript after div id my_camera. That's why "Could not locate DOM element "

Comment: Thank you for yuor suggestion ,initiate webcam after page load it working fine.

Comment: Hello shadowelf now webcam image will captured fine in my view page i update my view page above you can check,but i want to store this captured image in database and in path ,can you tell me how it works in codeigniter.